# Spring 3.0 MVC Handler Interceptors not working

Tags: spring, handler, interceptor

I am trying out the HandlerInterceptors from Spring MVC 3.0.

Below is my interceptor

```
public class SessionInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

   @Override public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("inside preHandle");
      if(request.getSession().getAttribute(SessionConsta nts.USER_SESSION_NAME) == null) {
         response.sendRedirect("welcome");
         return false;
      }
      return true;
   }
}
```

Below is my configuration in my xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<mvc:interceptors>
<mvc:interceptor>
<mvc:mapping path="/services/*"/>
<bean class="com.ca.myca.interceptors.SessionInterceptor " />
</mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

But the interceptor is not getting called.

Please let me know if I am missing any thing.

Answer (score 1):

In our application we are using double `**` for any service sub-path match, so try changing it and check if it helps:

```
<mvc:mapping path="/services/**"/>
```

Comment: I tried it, but still its not working. But if I use in the below way ..<mvc:interceptors> <bean class="com.ca.myca.interceptors.SessionInterceptor" />  </mvc:interceptors> ... interceptor is getting called for all requests. But i want to restrict it to some specific requests.

Comment: The `/services` part - is a context of your application? Because you don't have to specify it in interceptor mapping. In mapping path you just put the expression, which you put in your controllers request mapping value - `@RequestMapping(value="...")`

Comment: my context path is myca. and I had mentioned "/services" in the @Controller annotation in my controller class. and I have something like "/new" in [@RequestMapping] at a method level in the controller

Comment: post simplified code of your controller, so all annotations are visible - maybe then it will be possible to find something...

Comment: check out the answers to the similar question here, that worked for me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547972/spring-interceptor-is-never-called

Answer (score 1):

You are using `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` with mvc interceptor.

Please check on Spring reference:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html

*"When running in a Java 5+ environment, a default AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter will be registered as well. HandlerAdapter objects can be added as beans in the application context, overriding the default HandlerAdapters. Like HandlerMappings, HandlerAdapters can be given any bean name (they are tested by type)."*

`<mvc:annotation-driven/>` is supposed to be used for annotation-driven MVC controllers like @RequestMapping, @Controller etc, but I have seen there is no need to define "`<mvc:annotation-driven/>`" for supporting it.

Unless you are using jackson (for json support), you can try to remove `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` and use "`<context:annotation-config>`" instead for common use like autowiring etc.

Answer (score 0):

try what is suggested in [Configuration of Spring MVC and JSON using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733916/configuration-of-spring-mvc-and-json-using-jackson).

Put you interceptor in `<mvc:interceptors>` tag

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="xx.x..x..x...UserSessionInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

you can keep `<mvc:annotation-driven/> and <context:annotation-config>`

Answer (score 0):

In reference to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13280532/987044) above by [arviarya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409410/arviarya), <mvc:annotation-driven /> in the config XML results in a different handler Object being passed to the interceptor.  In our interceptor method we had:

```
@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView mav) throws Exception {
    if (mav != null && handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
        // something we want to have happen
    }
```

This was being called with the @Controller-derived object without the <mvc:annotation-driven />, but was called with the HandlerMethod-derivedobject when it was present.  For our if block to work, I needed the tag in our config XML.