# Configuration of Spring MVC and JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm using Spring MVC with Jackson. It requires `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. It works with it but it brings other issues. For example, after adding `<mvc:annotation-driven />`, Locale Change interceptor is not working:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I don't need it except for Jackson, is it possible to use it without `<mvc:annotation-driven />`? If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using mvc namespace to declare your interceptor

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But do you know the reason why this works while other approach not?