# spring interceptor is never called

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

I have the following interceptor:

```
@Component
public class ExternalLinkInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExternalLinkInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        logger.info("preHandle ~ invoked");
}
}
```

it is supposed to intercept before request handle to the following controller method:

```
@Controller
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
@RequestMapping("/assay/process")
public class VariantPrioritizationsController extends AssayBaseController{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(VariantPrioritizationsController.class);
@RequestMapping("/openAnalyticalProjectForAssay")
    public ModelAndView openAnalyticalProjectForAssay(HttpSession session,@RequestParam(value = "analyticalProjId", required=true)String projectId) throws PanDaApplicationException{
    //code 
     }
}
```

this is the interceptor declaration in the spring-servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/assay/process/openAnalyticalProjectForAssay*"/>
            <beans:bean class="com.syngenta.panda.web.mvc.interceptor.ExternalLinkInterceptor"/>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>
```

now my interceptor is never invoked and I don't know why?! any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try updating the mvc:mapping path to:

```
<mvc:mapping path="/assay/process/**" />
```

Comment: but this will make the interceptor intersept any request to this controller not to specific method

Comment: If this works, we atleast know that your interceptor is working and the path you specified is incorrect.

Comment: well, it worked and the interceptor preHandle is invoked now I need to do this only on the scope of my method not the controller

Comment: Please let us know, what urls are you referring? From that, I can figure it out what should be the mapping:path.

Comment: I have a link to my app, goes like this {host}/panda/assay/process/openAnalyticalProjectForAssay.htm?attr=12
the interceptor is to intercept this request, put specific objects in the session and let the request to be handled by the controller

Comment: so this handler is supposed to intercept only this link, but using the pattern provided it will intercept other requests

Answer (score -1):

The configuration for the mvc:interceptor doesn't look correct to me. I have used the locale change interceptors before from Spring and their configuration is very simple:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="language"/>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

This interceptor just looks for a param on the URL to change the locale that the user has selected.

This video walks through the setup of everything including the locale interceptor:

http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/springmvc-intro

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656124/proper-mvcinterceptor-configuration-in-spring

Comment: thanks for the video but I really don't understand the answer :-)

Comment: Ok, not really sure why I got a down vote for that. Your interceptor configuration doesn't look correct is what I was saying about your post. I expected there to be some dialog about what you were trying to do, like you did with the question above. I was thinking that you could try the simplest thing that works, like the LocaleChangeInterceptor, and get that working then add in the steps as you go.

Comment: Oh no worries, someone did. No big deal. I was just curious. :)